# Hecke eigenform with integer Fourier coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

Is it true that for any even $k$ and $N,$ there always exist a Hecke eigenform with integer Fourier co-efficient of weight $k$ and level $N$ ?

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: https://www.lmfdb.org/

Comment: Are you asking about holomorphic modular forms?  Cusp forms?  In either case, no as $M_2(1) = 0$.  If you exclude this example and allow Eisenstien series, then yes.

Comment: There are lots of Eisenstein series with integer coefficients, as several people have pointed out. CM forms (coming from Hecke characters over im. quad. fields) also often have small coefficient fields. On the other hand, I believe it's expected that if you fix an $N$ and look at cuspidal, non-CM eigenforms of level $N$, trivial character and weight $k$, then the degrees of the coefficient fields go to $\infty$ with $k$. The LMFDB database that @Pasten links to is a great way of getting a feel for this -- you can search by degree of coefficient field.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler This is also my feeling, but I don't know how to prove that even in the simplest case. E.g. how can one show that the only level $1$ eigenforms with $\Bbb Q$-coefficients are those of weight $12, 16, 18, 20, 22, 26$? Also it seems that for level $1$ and any weight, the coefficient field always has degree equal to the dimension (which implies the previous result). Is that true/proven? Heuristically I imagine that it's almost impossible for polynomials with such large coefficients to be reducible.

Comment: @WhatsUp The statement about level 1 modular forms is Maeda's conjecture. See here: https://orbilu.uni.lu/bitstream/10993/11499/1/%5Bbw%5DPTsaknias.pdf. There is lots of numerical evidence, everyone believes that it's true, and nobody has a clue how to prove it.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Thanks for the reply, I now find lots of information by searching for Maeda's conjecture.

Answer (score 1):

No, eg. $k$ odd and $N=1$. If $k=4m+6n$ then can't you just restrict an Eisenstein series for $N=1$ to a smaller group?

Comment: $k$ is even, sorry.